# RESTFull API Naming Standards

Tags: rest

We are designing Rest APIs. But I am little confused about endpoint naming convention. As per my understanding SOAP standard allows service endpoint name as **verb + noun** for example

```
getEmployee
deleteEmployee
changeEmployeeLocation
enableDisableEmployee
```

but in REST, we generally control names by the main entity and HTTP method. That is great for CURD operations. I am not sure how endpoints like changeEmployeeLocation will be named according to REST naming standards

```
getEmployee (SOAP) -> /employee (REST - GET HTTP Method)
deleteEmployee (SOAP) -> /employee (REST - DELETE Method)
changeEmployeeLocation (SOAP) -> ???
enableDisableEmployee (SOAP) -> ???
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RESTfully APIs, the verb is, as you guessed right, implied through the HTTP Method. The conceptual difference is, that you, unlike SOAP, do not call methods with REST. You only modify resources. Therefore you need to disassemble SOAP method calls like `enableDisableEmployee` into a correct resource-valid URL.

```
createEmployee (SOAP) -> POST /employees
getEmployee (SOAP) ->  GET /employees/1
deleteEmployee (SOAP) -> DELETE /employees/1
```

For updating a single attribute of a resource, we have two options:

```
PUT

changeEmployeeLocation (SOAP) -> PUT employees/1/location requestbody->{location:new location}
enableDisableEmployee (SOAP) -> PUT employees/1/enabled requestbody->{enabled:true}
```

Working with a specific URL does work, but it is very static. Therefore it would be better to use `PATCH`

```
PATCH

changeEmployeeLocation (SOAP) -> PATCH employees/1 requestbody->{location:new location}
enableDisableEmployee (SOAP) -> PATCH employees/1 requestbody->{enabled:true}
```

`PATCH` allows you to send a incomplete resource, which is expected to be merged with the existing resource.